# How to pass data to a child view controller from a previous segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller

I need to pass data from a `View Controller to a child of a parent view controller.`

`prepareSegue` isnt passing the data over.

i need to have it passed before viewdidload.

here is how im trying to pass info from  a View Controller to a Child of a Parent.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   // NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@",segue.identifier);

    ViewController2 *transfer = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Test"]) {
        transfer.testLabel = @"Pass this data";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code, after that I'll try to figure out why the data isn't passed. Regards, Alex

Comment: i assume you cant pass data from a VC to a child of a parent VC when pushing segue to the Parent?

Comment: @AlexWoe89 i updated my question with the code

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

If you're passing from a parent to a child view controller, then just set the property of your childViewController from the parent.

```
customChildViewController.someRandomProperty = @"some random value";
[self presentViewController:customChildViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Option 2**

Or, you can set up a delegate

*Step 1*: set up protocol above interface in ChildViewController.h file

```
@protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate

- (NSDictionary *) giveMeData;

@end

@interface  .....
```

*Step 2*: create delegate property in ChildViewController.h interface

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<ChildViewControllerDelegate>delegate
```

*Step 3*: declare delegate protocol in ParentViewController.h

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <ChildViewControllerDelegate>
```

*Step 4*: in ParentViewController.m add this method:

```
- (NSDictionary *) giveMeData {
    NSMutableDictionary * dataToReturn = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    dataToReturn[@"some"] = @"random";
    dataToReturn[@"data"] = @"here";
    return dataToReturn;
}
```

*Step 5*: before launching childViewController declare delegate property.

```
childViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:childViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

*Step 6*: in child view controller whenever you want data add this

```
NSMutableDictionary * dataFromParent = [self.delegate giveMeData];
```

The parentVC will run 'giveMeData' and return a NSMutableDictionary (adjust for whatever data you want)